# Vue 3 migration: INSTANCE_EVENT_EMITTER compat has been disabled

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I have migrated my project from Vue 2 to Vue 3. Now Iam getting the following error in console during Runtime:

```
INSTANCE_EVENT_EMITTER compat has been disabled.
    assertCompatEnabled vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:2539
    on vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:2585
    created mixin-sorting.js:185
    callWithErrorHandling vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:1668
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:1677
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:1687
    callHook...
```

I also have configured the Eventbus:

```
// eventBus.js
import emitter from 'tiny-emitter/instance'

export default {
    $on: (...args) => emitter.on(...args),
    $once: (...args) => emitter.once(...args),
    $off: (...args) => emitter.off(...args),
    $emit: (...args) => emitter.emit(...args)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventbus config provided in migration guide is the emitter object and you should import it everywhere you want to use that api:

```vue
<script>
  import emitter from './CustomEmitter.js';

  export default {
    mounted () {
      emitter.$emit('mounted');
    }
  }
</script>
```

OR, you could use that config as mixin, in your `main.js`:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import emitter from './CustomEmitter.js';

const app = createApp(App);
app.mixins(emitter);
app.mount('#app');
```

then you can call emitter API in your components this way:

```vue
<script>
  export default {
    mounted () {
      this.$options.$emit('mounted');
    }
  }
</script>
```

as you can see, all your methods stored in `$options` object.

if you want to keep the old fashioned Vue 2 API you should wrap it in `methods` object, like this:

```vue
export default {
  methods: {
    $on: (...args) => emitter.on(...args),
    $once: (...args) => emitter.once(...args),
    $off: (...args) => emitter.off(...args),
    // but you really want to use custom name for $emit, to avoid 
    // overriding native $emit function, used for component events
    $customEmit: (...args) => emitter.emit(...args)
  }
};
```

then you could use it in your components like so:

```vue
<script>
  export default {
    mounted () {
      this.$customEmit('mounted');
    }
  }
</script>
```